# Como dar fadeIn() em diferentes tempos em uma img e id

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer com que o texto apareça com um tempo e a imagem apareça com uma diferença de tempo um pouco maior, para dar um efeito mais interessante. O código html e js vou fornecer. O problema é que onde estão as imagens está no mesmo bloco que o texto.
HTML

```
<div class="span10">
                <div class="colorBody bodyForm">
                    <div id="show" style="display: none;">
                        <section >
                            <article class="textBox letra">
                                <header><h2>BOX banheiro</h2></header>
                                <span></span>
                                <br/>
                                <span></span>

                            </article>
                            <div class="imgRigth">
                                <img src="/img/box/bortovidros-1.jpg"/>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showBody(){
    $('#show').fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se a imagem está dentro da div que quer mostrar, então tem de "esconder" a imagem primeiro. Ou faz no HTML com `style="display: none;"` ou no javascript.

Se esconder no javascript o código seria:

```
function showBody(){
    $('#show img').hide().delay(500).fadeIn(1000); // usei o .delay(500) para atrasar a animação 0.5 segundos
    $('#show').fadeIn(1000);
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/rc655/

Se esconder no HTML pode fazer com `style="display: none;"` na tag do elemento `img` e retirar `.hide()` do código em cima.

Comment: Deu certo esta maneira, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Como o amigo @Sergio disse, você vai ter que esconder a imagem primeiro.

Uma outra maneira de você conseguir realizar esse procedimento em etapas é assim:

```
 <script>
 $(function(){
    $('.imgRigth').fadeTo(0, 0);
    $('#show').fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $('.imgRigth').fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });
 });
 </script>
```

No caso, como o fadeTo vai trabalhar sobre a opacidade do elemento (e não sobre a visibilidade), então você poderá trabalhar com os dois eventos separadamente.

O callback no segundo parâmetro passado no fadeIn serve para realizar uma ação após a transição do fadeIn ter sido completa.

Comment: Olha, não testei esse método, mas usarei isto em outros casos, foi muito útil, obrigado